# Basic binding with knockoutjs mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

It is my first time using knockoutjs so just trying to get my head around it.

I am trying to map some json to some html inputs with the knockoutjs mapping plugin.

I have the following json which I am receiving ok.

```
{"firstname":"it","lastname":"worked"}
```

I am mapping it with the code below:

```
var myProgram{
    viewModel : {},
    $.post(myServer, {}, function(data) {
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        });
}
```

And then trying to bind it...

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: firstname" id="text-firstname" placeholder="Text input" value="" data-mini="true" required />
```

However it doesn't work, and I'm not really sure where to look next to debug it. Is anybody able to help?

Comment: what is test.info?  I would think you would want something out of the data argument to pass into the mapping plugin;

Comment: Oops sorry when I was putting my example together had some old code left over it's fixed now. In that case test.info was just the data from the post request which is the json in the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed with:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Which is missing from the mappings getting started docs.